# Decryption of RSA with e that has no inverse

Tags: rsa, decryption

I'm studying the RSA protocol and I was wondering if there was any way of decrypting a message if the $e$ doesn't have an inverse $\mod (p-1)(q-1)$.

Usually, you have to choose a value of $e$ that is inverse $\mod (p-1)(q-1)$, but I made a mistake in my calculations. If someone where to write to me using the formula $C = M^e \bmod n$, would there be any way for me to decrypt it if my $e$ is wrong or am I out of luck.

Comment: What is the value of $e$? Is this textbook RSA? This seems like homework!

Comment: It's one of my friend who messed up his assignment and I'm trying to find a way to help him out. He sent a randomized $e$ instead of one that has an inverse with $(p-1)(q-1)$ the assignment is to open an excel file which the teacher sent us encrypted using our $e$. I don't think the $e$ alone can help you. I don't have it with me right now but I can send it later if you think it could help.

Comment: This means that $\gcd(e,\varphi(n) = d \neq 1$, you might get some information by working on $e/d$ and $n/d$, however, I'm not sure that the [xml](https://superuser.com/questions/850019/how-to-calculate-over-head-of-xml) can fit one RSA encryption.